# change apache tomcat homepage URL

Tags: apache, tomcat

I need to change the default home page of apache tomcat 6 to ":port/login.html" which is currently comes as ":port/".
This is required since my WLC redirects to a specific URL.
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind would be modifying the welcome-file-list in web.xml.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F

Another option would be to manually redirect in a Servlet or JSP.

```
request.sendRedirect('login.html');
```